# I'm looking for a way to load data from PHP in Android as PHP echoes the data

Tags: php, android, json, asynchronous

Right now, I'm using an ASYNC task to load data. In current case, php echoes the complete JSON, and then android reads the whole string and display it. Problem that I'm facing here is that, php takes time to echo the full data.Php does echo one entry in 2 sec. What I want is that, for my android device to read the response as it is coming, dont wait for the JSON to complete but read it as it is coming and display. Here is what the current code looks like

PHP:

```
<?php
while(entry!=0){
    data[] = processentry(entry);//will take 1-2 secs to process a single entry
    entry--;
}
echo json_encode(data);
?>
```

Android side:

```
URLConnection con = new URL("someURL").openConnection();
con.setDoOutput(true);
OutputWriter out = new OutputWriter(con.getOutputSream());
out.write(/* post params */);
out.close();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputReader(con.getInputStream));
while( (tmp = br.readline()) != null)
decodedStr += tmp;
```

decodedStr contained the complete json which can then be read by android device
I want PHP to echo in the while loop itself and let the android read as the data is recieved.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try some third party library like https://github.com/violet-php/streaming-json-encoder ? It should suit your needs.

Comment: `to read the response as it is coming, dont wait for the JSON to complete` ??? Your Android code is already reading while it is coming. Unclear what you want.

Comment: `decodedStr contained the complete json which can then be read by android device`. If decodedStr contains the complete json then all has already been read by your app. Unclear where you are talking about. Your post does not make sense.

Comment: `Php does echo one entry in 2 sec. ` Well that does not match with what you said before.

Comment: Again: your. Android app is already reading while it is coming. But you collect all -in the wrong way- in one string. And then you display that string you say. But code to display is not there.

Comment: `echo json_encode(data);` Remove that. And put something like `echo json_encode(data[]);` in the while loop.

Comment: @greenapps Android reads one line at a time. How can I make Php print one JSON object in one line, without going to next line?

Comment: Why would you print all in one line? The android code reads line by line and investigates if a line is a starting line. Or an end line. You grab all between start and end of such an echo.

Comment: But at php side you could also first remove the newline chars before echoing the json. Then you have all in one line.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set timeout once php finish it task you have to set timeout on android side

```
int ConnectTimeout=15000;
int ReadTimeout=15000;
con.setReadTimeout(ReadTimeout);
con.setConnectTimeout(ConnectTimeout);
```